# render a loop in PHP template system

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to create a simple template engine from scratch (not using any Smarty or twing or any other engine)
So far I can render a any variable with no problem, but I want to render a loop, in my case loop the array $stuff:
this is my class Engine.php:

```
class Engine {
    private $vars = array();

    public function assign($key, $value){
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function render($template_name){

        if (file_exists($template_name)){
            $content = file_get_contents($template_name);

            foreach ($this ->vars as $key => $value) {
                $content = preg_replace('/\{\{' . $key . '\}\}/', $value, $content);
            }


            eval(' ?> '. $content . '<?php');
        }else{
            exit('<h1>Template error</h1>');
        }
    }

}
```

And this is how I call it in index.php:

```
include_once 'Engine.php';
$template = new Engine;
$template->assign('Name', 'Ismail');
$stuff = array(
    array(
        Thing => "roses",
        Desc => "Red",
    ),
    array(
        Thing => "tree",
        Desc => "green",
    ),
    array(
        Thing => "Sky",
        Desc => "blue",
    ),
);

$template->assign('Stuff', $stuff);
$template->render('template.tmpl');
```

And here is my template.tmpl:

```
Hey {{Name}}, 
{{#each Stuff}}
  {{Thing}} are {{Desc}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I'd absolutley advise against reinventing the wheel again...

Comment: Please add potential errors and describe your problem more detailed. If you need any further advice on [how to ask read this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your advie, I have reasons to not include any other engine. could be better if you gave a try, thats why we are in SOF ;)

Comment: _I have reasons to not include any other engine..._ Re-think your reasons!

Comment: @creyD, I had no error in my execution, and I think I described enough my problem. my problem is to render a loop, thats it :)

Comment: @IsmailBerlin then you are wrong here. I don't really understand what you expect now, but we are not a code writing service. You try and fail, we will help you. But **not**: you provide information and we write code.

Comment: @creyD, I didnt ask for code, you didnt even give any sort of help, my question was clear, provided all my code which was already a "try". any idea could be helpful. the other asked me to "re-think", I could use Twig or smarty but if Im here then absolutely I dont need them.

Comment: Well if all you wanted was advice then I guess you got it.

Comment: @creyD was very helpful, wouldn't solve my problem without it xD

Comment: Like I said: Ask a specific problem and your attempts on the problem and we will try to help you to find errors in your code. Therefore you should provide your attempt and errors and we are happy to help. You can take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @creyD its not now after 7 years of SOF you will show me how to ask. maybe you thought I am new because of this fresh account ?? xD, thank you anyway.

Comment: If you got 7 years of experience then you should be able to aks a question properly. :) (You can merge your accounts BTW)

Answer (score 0):

You need to code your function. StackOverflow is here for others to help with problems, not create code for you.

To nudge you in a way I would implement it:

Call:

```
$template->assign('Stuff', array(
    array(
        Thing => "roses",
        Desc => "Red",
    ),
    array(
        Thing => "tree",
        Desc => "green",
    ),
    array(
        Thing => "Sky",
        Desc => "blue",
    ),
);
```

Engine:

```
foreach ($this ->vars as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        // process your loop here, probably with new foreach,
        // to populate $processedValue by content of your array in $value
        $content = preg_replace('/\{\{#each ' . $key . '.*' . '\/each\}\}/',
            $processedValue, $content);
    } else {
        $content = preg_replace('/\{\{' . $key . '\}\}/', $value, $content);
    }
}
```